# How to emulate window focus lost in Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, angular, automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress

I am writing E2E tests for a website using Cypress.io. One of the features I would like to test is that the site correctly detects focus lost and displays an (angular material) dialog box. The issue I am having is that I can not find a reliable way to trigger the window focus loss to occur in the testing environment. I have looked at the documentation for various focus and blur events in Cypress.io but am coming up empty. Does anyone know if it is possible to programmatically trigger a window focus loss (blur) from Cypress.io and if so is there documentation or examples I could follow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how your page is listening for this event, so there's a few potential solutions:

Try:

```
cy.window().trigger('blur')
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
cy.document().then((doc) => {
  cy.stub(doc, "hidden").value(true)
})
cy.document().trigger('visibilitychange')
```

In some cases

Comment: As it turned out, I only needed `cy.window().trigger("blur");` but this did help point me in the correct direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and the approved answer didn't work for me. But the code below is fine

```js
cy.document().then((doc) => {
  cy.stub(doc, "visibilityState").value("hidden") //or "visible" if you want focus
})
cy.document().trigger('visibilitychange')
```